# Password protect google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Is there any way to password protect google chrome browser? So that I can do "Remember password" on sites browsing in chrome in a shared computer and others can't access it

Comment: How would you like it if you sat down at a shared computer and Chrome was restricted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your system you could encrypt your Chrome Profile Folder (TrueCrypt in Windows, equivalent ones on other operating systems)

Before starting chrome, you mount your encrypted archive, then use

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="<location to profile>"
```

to start the browser using that directory.

P.S.: You can put a specific link on your desktop with the parameter for the profile location, so others can use chrome with the default profile.

Comment: I'm afraid that's only giving the illusion of security. It's very much like getting a new car and putting the keys in a safe. Chrome is not very secure password-wise. The userprofile is only one place Chrome can write to.

Comment: Sure, but if it's in a secure archive it is protected from others who use that computer.

Answer (score 2):

One more useful tool very similar to Truecrypt - Rohos Mini Drive. I'm using it's feature - Hide folder to password protect my Google Chrome profile - http://www.rohos.com/2010/12/how-to-password-protect-google-chrome-data-with-rohos-encryption-software/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Chrome doesn't allow you to password protect user profiles anymore.

Basically, you load your Chrome Profile from an encrypted volume using Veracrypt residing in the computer or your external USB drive. When you're done, close Chrome and simply unmount the volume. You can do similar for Windows or Mac OS but specifics may differ. You may need admin privileges to mount/unmount.

Here is my setup in my Ubuntu 18.04:

First create a new User Profile in Chrome.

Open Terminal

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome 
ls -al
```

You should see a new profile directory that is just created say, 'Profile 4'.

Sync to your Google profile and all Chrome extensions now if you like so you know roughly how much space to allocate on the encrypted volume. Example:

```
du -ch 'Profile 4'
```

## Create encrypted Veracrypt volume file

Download GUI or Console version of Veracrypt for your OS distribution.

Create encrypted volume file somewhere not so obvious example:

```
touch ~/.config/profile.vc
```

Here is an example of using Veracrypt from the Terminal to create 256 MB (check your space requirement) Ext4 encrypted volume for your User Profile. You can use the GUI version if you want.

```
veracrypt -t -c --volume-type=normal ~/.config/profile.vc --size=256M --encryption=aes --hash=sha-512 --filesystem=ext4 --pim=0 -k "" --random-source=/dev/urandom
```

You will be prompted to assign your password. Also, enter administrator password if asked.

Mount Veracrypt volume you just created. Your mount directory now becomes something like `/media/veracrypt1`

After mount is successful, close Veracrypt GUI if you are in a shared computer.

Exit any running Chrome applications – important!

Move chrome profile directory to your encrypted volume.

```
mv 'Profile 4' /media/veracrypt1/.
```

Create a symbolic link.

```
ln -s "/media/veracrypt1/Profile 4" 'Profile 4'
```

Open Chrome and you can now switch to your user profile from encrypted volume.

When done, quit the whole Chrome application.

Then unmount your encrypted drive from Veracrypt and open Chrome again. You'll see your extra Chrome Profile avatar but can't switch into it.

## Script for convenience

Create a bash script and make it executable.

```
touch ~/.config/profile 
chmod +x ~/.config/profile 
vim ~/.config/profile
```

Add the following to the bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash 
VOL=~/.config/profile.vc
if [ $1 -eq 1 ] 
then 
    echo "Mounting..." 
    veracrypt -t -k "" --pim=0 --protect-hidden=no $VOL /media/veracrypt1
    sleep 2
    nohup google-chrome --profile-directory='Profile 4' &>/dev/null &

elif [ $1 -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo "Dismounting..."
    pkill --oldest chrome
    sleep 2
    veracrypt -t -d $VOL
else
    echo "Usage: ./profile 0 or ./profile 1"
fi
```

## Usage

To **mount** encrypted volume and open Chrome using your user profile

```
. ~/.config/profile 1    # Prompts for your password :)
```

To close Chrome and **unmount** encrypted volume

```
. ~/.config/profile 0
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's passwords are encrypted with your login password, at least on Windows, though very weakly. I'm going to have to say that it's a bad idea to use the browser's built-in password manager no matter what. Google Chrome can import Firefox's passwords even if Firefox's passwords are under a master password.

Use a dedicated password manager that is at least reasonably secure. The safest is probably KeePass because it's been around for quite a while. Lastpass is another option that is reasonably secure, but if you're working on the CIA, keep in mind that it hasn't been audited by any independent organization yet (KeePass hasn't been audited either, but it's open source, so thousands of people can and have read through the code for security flaws and those flaws are fixed very quickly).

In summary: if you're paranoid, use KeePass. If not, use LastPass.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [LastPass](http://lastpass.com) plugin to have an online and extremely secure password vault. Just turn off automatic login and your set. It even has the bonus advantage of a web interface and portability.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Discolock](http://discobytes.com/?page_id=87) a freeware small utility, which password protect many applications.

Answer (score 0):

On the Chrome toolbar
click on the ‘+” sign to open a new tab
left click on the “3” vertical dots at the far right with your mouse
when the menu opens, click on “settings”
the “search” bar will show a “navy blue chrome Icon”   followed by the word “Chrome”, a vertical line, then chrome://settings

the menu that opens up after left or right clicking with your mouse on the word “settings” brings up a new menu that starts with the word “People” as a heading, followed by a vertical list starting with your Google sign in that shows “Syncing to XXXXXXX@gmail.com”, etc. (see pic)

From this list, click on the “Passwords” word
Now you will see in the “address/search bar”: “Chrome | chrome://settings/passwords”

From here you take your mouse and left click and “Hold” on the nave blue chrome icon in the “address/search bar”.

“DRAG” that “navy blue chrome icon” to your toolbar where you have your “other” shortcuts and
VOILA !

YOU NOW HAVE A SHORTCUT TO YOUR PASSWORDS RIGHT ON YOUR TOOLBAR…

…it will now show a “navy blue ‘settings’ icon” with the word “Settings” next to it.

Now every time you open your Chrome browser, it will be there for you to access in “ONE CLICK”

Comment: The question asked how to prevent other people getting access to the passwords,not how to make them easier to access,

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [a **Dashlane** extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dashlane-password-manager/fdjamakpfbbddfjaooikfcpapjohcfmg) for Chrome which connects to [**Dashlane**](https://www.dashlane.com/) password manager.

Using this app, you can import all your Google passwords (since it's [not clear how they're secured](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/96011/11825)), and after importing consider [removing them all](https://superuser.com/q/1106689/87805) as they're still stored in the cloud and you can see your of all passwords by going to https://passwords.google.com/

See also:

- [Dashlane Security White Paper [2018]](https://www.dashlane.com/download/Dashlane_SecurityWhitePaper_October2018.pdf)
- [Security analysis of Dashlane](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74656/security-analysis-of-dashlane)