# How can I protect Chrome user interface?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface

Google Chrome has a feature to change between Google accounts which allows several users to have their customized extensions, history and whatnot retrieved instantly. It doesn't, however, protect someone else from checking anything google related. That means anyone with access to your computer can check every google account that was setup as user in Chrome.

How can I prevent that? I first thought of checking a box with the option to have Chrome request for password upon user change but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. The [multiple profile support](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) in Chrome is only for convenience and was never intended to be used as a security feature.

You will have to create separate user accounts in your OS to achieve any sort of security. In Windows, use *Control Panel → User Accounts*; in Mac OS X, *Apple menu > System Preferences → Accounts*.

> #### [Manage multiple users on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824)
>
> The ability to add multiple users to Chrome is intended to provide a quick and simple way to set up personalized copies of Chrome for people who are already sharing Chrome on the same computer today. It isn’t intended to secure your data against other people using your computer. To truly protect your data from being seen by others, please use the built-in user accounts in your operating system of choice.

Comment: It’s also helpful to think of the profiles as different setups for the *same person*. For example, you may have a couple of aliases, or have a work profile and personal one, etc. In that case, security from other people isn’t even expected.

Comment: Damnit. It would make my life so much easier. =/

Answer (score 0):

You can password protect your Google user profile directory (or multiple accounts) inside a [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/) encrypted drive. When you want to use it, mount your password-protected drive and unmount when you are done so other users can't access your encrypted user profile/Google account without knowing the password. Here is how I did it: https://superuser.com/a/1579901/141949