# How do I delete ALL Chrome/Google Account stored website passwords at once?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, google-accounts

I have hundreds of them, it takes .6 seconds to delete one in the browser and 3.7 seconds to delete one in the Google Account management page.

There has to be a way to remove all of them at once... right?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Found it. Clearing all the saved passwords in Chrome from `Clear browsing data...` also deletes the synced passwords in the Google Account. The setting can be revealed by clicking on the Advanced Tab.

Comment: I did just that (since "the beginning of time'). STILL they were all on 'passwords.google.com'. You have [to go there, too](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync) and choose Reset Sync. — Better keep checking a day or two later, that truly all your local chrome sync settings don't re-upp...

Comment: It seems removing them separately from passwords.google.com is no longer needed. I just cleared all the passwords in Chrome, and they disappeared also from passwords.google.com immediately.

Comment: This does not delete the passwords stored on your Google account. When you sign in again to another device, they will re-sync. You have to manually delete each one in chrome://settings/passwords

Answer (score 40):

The fastest way to clear all Chrome passwords is with this shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

That'll open the "Clear browsing data" window.

Click the Advanced tab, then choose a time range. Choose "All time" if you want to delete all passwords. Click the checkbox for "Passwords and other sign-in data". Click the blue button "Clear data" and then wait:

[image: Tick the Passwords box then "Clear data"]

It can take a long time to delete the passwords and other cached items (it took 20 minutes for my Chrome to clear 1200 passwords and 350MB cached pages/images).

Comment: This works, and clears passwords.google.com

Comment: passwords.google.com seems to have a different layout now that isn't deleted when doing the above :(

Comment: POS Google is spinning forever to clear mine with just 15 pwds - ..maybe btards are saving it all to their other servers - I switched from Vivaldi to Chrome again just cause I was being wary - now again :(

Comment: Its not working...bastrds have just got it spinning doing nada..whats the big idea I wonder

Comment: @killjoy The steps above still work for me. I've updated the screenshot. Please try again using the above steps and confirm whether it works for you.

Comment: @DanRoberts u r right..it did work, was just spinning but it was done

Comment: The above steps still work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by @bill-mcgonigle I assume it would also be possible to just use the Chrome Console

```
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }
for (let button of window.document.querySelectorAll('div[role=grid] > div[jsmodel] > div[role=gridcell] > div[role=button]')) {
    if (typeof button != undefined) {
        button.click();
        sleep(3100);
    }
}
```

This worked for me, after the first time you run it, Google will ask for your password again. After that my 200+ passwords were deleted without any issue.

Please note there's a warning in the console to understand the risk of running anything there. Be advised, read the above carefully to understand what you run.

Clarification:

```
// function to wait for 3 seconds before clicking the next delete button
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }
// start a loop iteration of all buttons inside the password grid
// please note there are two grids on the page
for (let button of window.document.querySelectorAll('div[role=grid] > div[jsmodel] > div[role=gridcell] > div[role=button]')) {
    // in my debugging there was one undefined button
    if (typeof button != undefined) {
        // click that exact button element
        button.click();
        // wait for 3.1 seconds
        sleep(3100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this still working ? if I go to passwords.google.com what I get is a list of accounts. To delete a password I have to manually click on an item of the list then it redirect me to a new page where I can finally delete it. It seems script you gave expect you can delete them all by simply clicking on a single button.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution is working for now (Mid 2019).

Run this Javascript code in the console, or make it into a bookmarklet, or in Chrome Snippets:

```
function contains(selector, text) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element) {
        return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
    });
}

function simulateMouseClick(targetNode) {
    function triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
    ["mouseover", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"].forEach(function(eventType) {
        triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType);
    });
}

function clicker() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("c-wiz>div>ul>li");
    if (document.location.href.match(/\/password\//) == null) {
        simulateMouseClick(list[list.length - 1]);
    } else if (contains('span', /^Delete$/).length > 0) {
        var del = contains('span', /^Delete$/);
        del[0].click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            var del = contains('span', /^Delete$/);
            del[del.length - 1].click()
        }, 500)
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        clicker();
    }, 1500)
}
clicker();
```

It will click its way through the deletion of all your passwords while keeping your actual mouse cursor free.

You will still have to babysit it, though because Google periodically ask you to re-enter your password.

I don't expect this to work forever... any change to the Google UI will break this script.

Comment: Stopped working already.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this scenario where I only wanted to delete a large number of specific passwords. Finding no suitable alternative, I created a macro with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com) that deletes 10 at a time:

[chrome remove bulk passwords.kmmacros](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R-sstDMjuB1VAr1aI2Kmh-kkYldWf74f/view?usp=sharing)

The file can be viewed for security purposes on Google Drive or in a text editor (the .kmmacros files are XML formatted) and can easily be modified to delete hundreds at a time.

All it does is clicks at the current mouse location, clicks 40 pixels below, and returns the cursor to the original location, repeating 9 more times.

Answer (score 1):

To delete all passwords from https://passwords.google.com/ and other personal data stored in the Google cloud, follow these steps:

1. Go to: https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync
2. Click on: *Reset Sync*.

> This will stop sync and clear your synced Chrome data from Google servers. The copy of your data stored on each of your devices will not be deleted.

Source: [How can I delete multiple saved passwords in my google account (passwords.google.com)?](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/3509905)

Comment: And then, you can clear the unsynced data from your mobile device the way you would clear data from any other app.

Answer (score 0):

For X11 systems, you can load passwords.google.com and on the saved passwords page put the mouse over the top trash-can icon and from a terminal do:

`watch -n 3 xdotool click 1`

and keep the mouse over the trash can icon until it's done - the next undeleted password will move up after each previous one has been deleted.

Now, Google seems to sign you out at 5 minutes sharp for each p.g.c session, so this method can only do a hundred at a time (my goodness, 20 years of saved passwords...) but it's less maddening than clicking each one individually.  Google does appear to impose a 3-second delay between each delete event.  I tried fiddling with random delays and mouse wiggles, but those don't affect the 5-minute timeout.

This method also works for the 'never save passwords for ...' section, but it will error out if any of those are of the chrome-extension:// protocol type, in which case you will need to move the cursor down one manually.

I did do the Chrome-side tip given above to delete all passwords, but as soon as I turned on an old device it uploaded them all again.  :angry react:

That Google makes this so darn hard to do is probably reason enough to think that it's a good idea.